# Better way to copy multiple directories to new directory

Tags: command-line, directory, cp

Is there a better way on the command line to essentially accomplish the following but with a single command

```
cp -r css/ ar/
cp -r images/ ar/
cp -r js/ ar/
cp -r backups/ ar/
```

I've just been stringing them together with a semicolon.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Copying folders into another folder (folder in folder):

```
cp -r css images js backups ar/
```

**Note:** this is different from copying just the contents themselves(contents of folders in folder):

```
cp -r css/ images/ js/ backups/ ar/
```

Comment: the slashes make a difference! always suspected, never knew

Comment: slashes don't make a difference in my testing. `cp` is not `rsync`. however `cp -r css/. images/. ar/` does copy the contents without the directories. my cp version is "cp (GNU coreutils) 8.29".

Comment: My god... thank you for that nuance. I was wasting a lot of time trying to figure that out.

Comment: also, just to add
cp -rv * ar/
Will copy every folder, if the assumption is that you just simply want everything

Comment: @the_5imian How would you copy the contents of every folder using `*`

Answer (score 9):

I am on `Ubuntu 18.04.3` and use the following command to copy multiple folders in one directory:

```
cp -r /source_directory/{folder1,folder2,folder3} /destination
```

**Equals**

```
cp -r /source_directory/folder1 /destination
cp -r /source_directory/folder2 /destination
cp -r /source_directory/folder3 /destination
```

I think it's a very clean method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, and it works on Debian "this is actually how i did it" (tested)
lets say you're in **/etc** and want to copy some files and folders before you format your hard disk (for some reason) you'd type the following and everything mentioned below will be copied to **/mybackups/** folder:

```
sudo cp -r -a apt/ bash.bashrc environment hosts init.d/ init/ nginx/ proxychains.conf sudoers sysctl.d/ profile.d/ grub.d/ /boot/grub/ /opt/ /root/ /var/www/ /mybackups/
```

as you can see above, i tried to copy folders from outside **etc** as well by pointing to its location like **/boot/grub/** or **/opt/** and it worked!

Comment: I believe -r there is not needed, as -a already contains it (via: man).

Answer (score -1):

if you want to copy all the folder's in a directory into another folder.

```
cp -r * /anotherfolder/
```

if you want to copy some files or folders.

```
cp -r folder1 folder2 folder3 /anotherfolder
```

Answer (score -2):

cp -r css images js backups ar/
should work, Note that in order to copy a directory on Linux, you have to execute the cp command with the r  recursive option.

Comment: This solution has already been covered by [porton's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68456/414186)

Answer (score -3):

You can't copy two directories using `cp` command alone.

You can copy recursively using `-r` option though.

For example:

```
cp -r <source> <destination>
```